# Layout for images in array

Tags: javascript, php, css, arrays, foreach

Here's the layout.

[image]

Basically, I'm getting images in array and trying to create a gallery with this layout. Not sure how to go about this. I tried grid and also :nth-child(even) and :nth-child(odd) but it's still not working out.

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($images as $image) :?>
      <li><img src="<?php echo $image['url'] ;?>"></li>
    <?php endforeach ;?>
</ul>
```

Link to jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/u5tgLj27/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

we can do like this

```
ul {
max-width:90%;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:space-between;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type:none;
  width:calc(50% - 10px);
}
ul li:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  width:100%;
}
ul li img {
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Instead using widt:100%; i think it's better use flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 10px); and use column gap for margin between columns

Comment: This works. Thanks @vinay. @ sfili, what's the reason behind using flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 10px) instead of width:100% ?

Comment: @Sfili_81 please share an example

Comment: [flex-properties](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/). And an example [https://jsfiddle.net/d7exjthv/](https://jsfiddle.net/d7exjthv/)

Comment: @Sfili_81 what's the advantage of using your method over vinay's ? sorry, just trying to understand this.

Comment: _It makes the flex item inflexible when there is some free space left, but allows it to shrink to its minimum when there is not enough space._ Read more about it in the article from my previous comment

Comment: @shutupchigo he is right you can use flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px) instead of width:calc(50% - 10px); and flex:0 0 100%; instead of width:100%;